# Convert VideoView to Grayscale android java

Tags: android, android-videoview

I would like to know if there is a way to convert video using VideoView from RGB to Gray without using any external library (such as OpenCV).

I didn't found anything about it.

All that I found is to manipulate the video before display him, by using FFMPEG, using OpenCV that I don't need for this project or do manipulation on SurfaceView using OpenGL.

Is there any way to do the manipulation directly on the VideoView?

**Update**

I found the solution for this problem, by just use this [Library](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "external library". Manipulation with OpenGL ES is the most efficient approach. Are you asking whether VideoView inherently supports video filters?

Comment: Actually, I found an external library that does what I need, this is the one https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects, it gives me what I need, but now I have another problem. so fo this problem I found the answer and I will update the quesion for this.